# how to use "setInterval" with "while loop".?

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop, setinterval

I check all documants about setinterval from forum but.. I couldnt find what I want... Here is my question.:

my code is below:

```
<?php
include('database_connection.php');
$sorgu = $baglanti->query("select * from makale");
while ($sonuc = $sorgu->fetch_assoc())  {
 ?>
```

MY TABLE CODE HERE.. ( codes like :   `<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>` )

```
<?php }  ?>
```

I call datas to my table from mysql.. But I change database from admin panel..

And What I want is when I change some data from adminpanel... My users will see it immediatly in few sec with `setInterval` code without refreshing page...

How can I do that in my documants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to refresh the page automatically after few seconds:

```
<script>
// Auto-refresh the page after 5 seconds:
setTimeout(function() {
  document.location.reload(true);
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Mr Armelin, can I also disable "refreshing"  icon in web page every 5 sec? it will distrub users :S